# Why is the dictionary returning None in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Why is the dictionary returning `None` here?

```py
alpha = {"A":"1", "B":"2", "C":"3"}
text = "ABC"
out = " "

for x in text.split():
    if x != " ":
        print(alpha.get(x))
```

Comment: Replace `text.split()` with `text`.

Comment: Because `split` with no parameters splits the string into words.  There's only one word there, "ABC", so the loop will run once with x == "ABC".

Comment: Check what `'ABC'.split()` actually returns and then read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not specified how the string `text` shout be `split` so the python would be just returning that string in a list:

```
>>> text ='ABC'
>>> text.split()
>>> text
```

OUTPUT:

```
 >>> ['ABC']
```

So as it returns the string `'ABC'` and that string is not in the dict `alpha` so the Output ur getting is the `None` because `alpha.get(x)` would be finding for a key with the name `'ABC'` but as there is no such key it would be returning `None`.